# Created a Google Form; can't find the Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Long ago, I created a survey that I sent out by email. The responses were recorded in a Google Spreadsheet by filling out a Google Form.

I would like to use that data again, but I cannot find the original spreadsheet. I simply misplaced it. But I ***do*** have the original email with a link to the survey that I sent to the candidates.

If I am the owner of the original spreadsheet, is there a way for me to work my way back from the response form to the original spreadsheet?

Comment: @pnuts No, all I have is the email that contains a link to the survey that the original respondents took.

Comment: @pnuts Interesting; can you filter the files listing to see only forms? I would still like an answer to the question (how to I find my way from the survey back to the original form/spreadsheet), but barring that, filtering the file listings *would* make it easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

The link you still have, contains the ID of the form you created. Building the following URL will bring you to the original form in edit modus.

> `https://docs.google.com/a/<yourdomainname>/forms/d/<yourformid>/edit`

If you select from the menu *Responses(?) > View responses*, then it will lead you to the corresponding Google Spreadsheet. Tried it on my account and it worked.